# How to handle request on the page that was previously forwarded by servlet?

Tags: jsp, url, tomcat, redirect, forward

I have a JSP page that has 2 forms running on Tomcat 6. One is register form, Second is login form.
(please pay attention to context path, it's going to kill me later)

(regis_and_login.jsp)

```
    <% String path = request.getContextPath(); %>

    //regis form
    <form id="regis_form" name="register_form" 
action="<%= path %>/servlet/process_register" method="post">

     //login form
    <form name="login_form" action="<%= path %>/servlet/login" method="POST">
```

**GOAL**

If insert statement to add new user fails, I want to redirect the user back to regis_and_login.jsp page with my custom error displayed.

**servlet behavior**

(login servlet)

If login fails, my custom error message is added to request (i.e. `request.setAttribute("error", "there is error!")` and dispatcher will forward back to the `regis_and_login.jsp` page and displays the error message properly but since this is **forward**, URL changes FROM http://localhost:8080/regis_and_login.jsp TO http://localhost:8080/servlet/login

(RegisterServlet)
Register servlet works same way. If any error is detected, I call setAttribute() on request and call RequestDispatcher's forward function to redirect the user back to regis_and_login.jsp page with my custom error displayed.

**PROBLEM**

Each form works fine individually but when used together, it has some problem.

1. Fill in invalid input to login form so you get redirected back to http://localhost:8080/servlet/login with my custom message properly showing up.
2. On the same page (http://localhost:8080/servlet/login), fill in the registration form and submit.

Result:

Now the URL looks crazy.

```
The requested resource (/servlet/servlet/process_register) is not available.
```

My guess is this is because in `regis_and_login.jsp`, I set contextPath and concatenate to form's action value: `action="<%= path %>/servlet/process_register`

So I believe after the URL is modified by forwarding (http://localhost:8080/servlet/login), contextPath is now set to "/servlet/" and that's why I am requesting `/servlet/servlet/process_register` instead of just `/servlet/process_register` ?

There are few options in my mind:

1. Just use absolute path to form's action path
2. Instead of forwarding, use response.sendRedirect(address) to stay away from URL change (but this disallow me to set attribute on request so I can't display error message on my JSP page..this is against my goal)

Should I just use absolute path?

Please let me know if you need more clarification..

**UPDATE**

I asked help desk to remove mount directives and now it accepts all incoming request. The web.xml and form action URL no longer mentions "/servlet" and code started working just fine. Now I think the reason for having extra "/servlet", I wonder if it is due to the mount directive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but since this is forward, URL changes FROM http://localhost:8080/regis_and_login.jsp TO http://localhost:8080/servlet/login

This phrase is a bit odd. A forward doesn't change the URL at all. A forward just points to another resource (Servlet or JSP) to continue processing the **current** HTTP request. The URL change is caused because the form action URL is different from the original request URL. You're firing a synchronous POST request on this URL. The URL in the browser address bar becomes the form action URL.

> Now the URL looks crazy.
>   The requested resource (/servlet/servlet/process_register) is not available.

So, in the beginning you have a context path of `"/"` and after submitting the form it becomes `"/servlet"`? Sorry, the problem is caused by something else. Is your webapplication deployed as ROOT? Are you running the code you think you're running?

---

However, I have two recommendations how to approach this issue differently:

1. Don't map the servlets on `/servlet/process_register` and `/servlet/login` but just on `/process_register` and `/login`.

   ```
   <form action="process_register" method="post">
   ...
   <form action="login" method="post">
   ```
2. Or, hide the JSP file away in `/WEB-INF` folder, use a single servlet on `/register_and_login` for both GET and POST and let the servlet execute the desired action depending on the button pressed. This way the URL stays http://localhost:8080/register_and_login all the time.

Comment: Yes, the form action URL does the URL change not a forward. (thanks for the correction)  I will look into the approach 1 and see if this URL issue resolves. Will update the result later ;)

Comment: Another thing I discovered is that my hosting server has mount directive set to "/servlet", that is the reason I had to follow even though the links you gave me in other post says it's bad practice. Fortunately they can remove it so will see!